# Panel In Syncfusion

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

Is there any way can we create panel in syncfusion, which can be expandable and collapsible? I wish to give name to the panel, and add related controls to inside the panel.

Answer (score 1):

We have Sidebar component that typically acts as a side container to place primary or secondary content alongside the main content. By clicking a hamburger menu icon, you can expand or collapse the sidebar. The component can also allow any type of HTML content or component to be placed in the Sidebar, like menus, lists, and tree views, etc.,

To know more about Sidebar component, refer the below links.

Demo : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/Sidebar/DefaultFunctionalities#/fluent

Documentation : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/sidebar/getting-started

The Dashboard Layout component provides the capability to arrange, resize, and reorder the panels within the layout. The Dashboard Layout is a layout component which can be used to render custom components like Grid, Chart, etc., You can also interact with the panels, to perform operations like resizing or moving the panels. But it can’t be able to do the expand and collapse functions.

To know more about Dashboard Layout component, refer the below links.

Demo : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/DashboardLayout/DefaultFunctionalities#/fluent

Documentation : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/dashboard-layout/getting-started

Also, we have an Accordion component with the support of expand and collapse functions. It’s a vertically collapsible content panel that displays content, one or multiple at a time, within the available space. Click on the header element to expand or collapse the corresponding Accordion panel to display its content.

To know more about Accordion Layout component, refer the below links.

Demo : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/Accordion/DefaultFunctionalities#/fluent

Documentation : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/accordion/getting-started#add-aspnet-core-accordion-control

Kindly check whether any of the above shared component suits your requirement.